# "sys/ioctl.h" header in linux

Tags: linux, c, header-file

I am on `Linux 2.6.32-26-generic`

When I look in to the linux source code for "ioctl.h" hearer file, I could see many variants. (for different platforms, I guess). i.e.

```
./fs/ocfs2/ioctl.h
./fs/btrfs/ioctl.h
./fs/ceph/ioctl.h
./include/config/i2o/config/old/ioctl.h
./include/asm-generic/ioctl.h
./include/linux/hdlc/ioctl.h
./include/linux/ioctl.h
./drivers/video/via/ioctl.h
./drivers/staging/vt6655/ioctl.h
./drivers/staging/vt6656/ioctl.h
./arch/ia64/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/h8300/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/microblaze/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/score/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/avr32/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/alpha/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/x86/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/m32r/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/mn10300/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/sparc/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/powerpc/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/m68k/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/sh/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/xtensa/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/mips/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/s390/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/arm/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/blackfin/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/frv/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/parisc/include/asm/ioctl.h
./arch/cris/include/asm/ioctl.h
```

But I see that file being included as `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`

How does this mapping work?

Comment: Is this more appropriate for `stackoverflow`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe file is being included is `/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h` (not from /usr/src/linux or some). And on my system it belongs to glibc, not kernel or kernel-headers.

Actually, nothing gets included from kernel source - headers inside /usr/src/linux (or so) are being used only for kernel compilation. If some software needs some kernel headers to compile it uses ones in `/usr/include/linux` (and some others), which are usually part of package like `kernel-headers` or `linux-headers`.

Answer (score 4):

The default search path for include files is `/usr/include`. This is a property of the C compiler, and in theory different compilers could use different paths, but in practice they all look in `/usr/include` (and a few other compiler-dependent places).

`#include <sys/ioctl.h>` means to look for a file called `sys/ioctl.h` relatively to an entry in the include path, thus `/usr/include/sys/ioctl.h`.

The headers in the kernel source are not relevant unless you are compiling a kernel module (or the kernel itself). Headers for userland programs come with the C library or with the C compiler.